# Styling not getting applied after printing the dynamically creating component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have running Angular 9 application and I am integrating print functionality by dynamically creating component. The print functionality works as expected but the css properties of print-report.component.scss files are not getting applied on when the print window opens.

**print.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class PrintService {

    constructor(
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private injector: Injector
    ) { }

    showDialog(component) {
        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        
        const dialogComponentRef = factory.create(this.injector);
        dialogComponentRef.instance.title = 'Print page';
        
        dialogComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

        //fetch the root DOM element of ModalComponent
        const domElement = (dialogComponentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
        
        const WindowPrt = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
        WindowPrt.document.write(domElement.innerHTML);
        WindowPrt.document.close();
        WindowPrt.focus();
        WindowPrt.print();
        WindowPrt.close();
    }

}
```

**print-report.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-print-report',
    templateUrl: './print-report.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./print-report.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class PrintReportComponent {

    @Input() title: string;    
}
```

**print-report.component.html**

```
<div class="name">{{title}}</div>
```

**print-report.component.scss**

```
.name { // these styles are not getting applied when print window opens
   color: red;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

**my-custom-component.ts**

```
constructor(private printService: PrintService){}

onButtonClick(){
    this.printService.showDialog(PrintReportComponent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are adding to the new document just the HTML.
The faster solution should be

```
showDialog(component) {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    
    const dialogComponentRef = factory.create(this.injector);
    
    dialogComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

    //fetch the root DOM element of ModalComponent
    const domElement = (dialogComponentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
    
    const WindowPrt = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    WindowPrt.document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML;
    WindowPrt.document.body.innerHTML = domElement.outerHTML;
    WindowPrt.document.close();
    WindowPrt.focus();
    WindowPrt.print();
    WindowPrt.close();
}
```

The better solution should be read the component css file and add it to the head.

Comment: Thanks @viltor, it worked. Also, can u plz tell me how to read the component css file. I tried with WindowPrt.document.write(`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../print-report.component.scss" type="text/css>`); but it was not working

Comment: Avoid to use document.write, use document.head.innerHTML = ...
Also, dont use relative paths. But if in that way doesnt work, i should use a httpClient for obtain it.
But in your case, is not a problem use the document.head because is for print.